# Render New/Create and Edit/Update form on same page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have two controllers, `Boards` and `Sections`. `Sections` are nested in `Boards` and one `Board` can have many `Sections`. On the Show page of `Boards` I want to have the ability to both create a new `Section` and edit it.

Currently I have the form to create a new `Section` on the `Boards` show page but I haven't found a way to reuse this form for the edit method.

## Boards#show

```
<%= render 'sections/shared/form', board: @board, section: @section %>
<br>

<% @board.sections.order(id: :asc).each_with_index do |section, index| %>
  <%= "#{index + 1}. #{section.title}" %>
  <% if policy(section).edit? %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_board_section_path(@board, @board.sections[index]) %>
  <% end %>
  <% if policy(section).destroy? %>
    <%= link_to("Delete", board_section_path(@board, @board.sections[index]), method: :delete) %>
  <% end %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

## Form partial

```
<%= simple_form_for([@board, @section]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

The `edit_board_section_path` basically duplicates the form partial.

How can I make it that the Edit button next to a section allows me to edit a section on the Boards#show page itself? I don't want to reconnect to another page to edit the form but display it directly on Boards#show.

Comment: Can you show your current edit template?

Comment: @arieljuod This is the edit template:                                                                  `<%= simple_form_for([@board, @section]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.submit "Save changes" %>
<% end %>`

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve. Why can't you just render the partial on the edit template?

Comment: Sorry,  maybe I wasn't clear here. I only want to  show the edit template on the Boards#show page after the user has clicked on 'Edit'. Ideally I don't want to redirect  to another page but have this edit form appear directly on the current  page after clicking on 'Edit'.

Comment: I added a button/javascript to show what it could look like to toggle the edit form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to change the form partial to use the passed in variables, `board` and `section`, not the variables prefixed with `@`. Adding `remote: true` will let you submit via AJAX.

```rb
<%= simple_form_for([board, section], remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

With that change made, the render for the new section will still work as you currently have. To add an edit form for each existing section you can do the following:

```
<%# index.html.erb %>
<div id="sections">
    <% @board.sections.order(id: :asc).each_with_index do |section, index| %>
            <%= render partial: 'sections/section', section: section, index: index %>
    <% end %>
</div>

<script>
window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.matches('.edit-form-toggle')) {
        event.target.parentElement.querySelector('.edit-form').classList.toggle('hidden');
    }
});
</script>
<style>
.hidden { display: none; }
</style>

<%# sections/_section.html.erb %>
<div id="section-<%= section.id %>
    <%= "#{index + 1}. #{section.title}" %>
    <% if policy(section).edit? %>
        <button class="edit-form-toggle">Edit</button>
        <div class="edit-form hidden">
            <%= render 'sections/shared/form', board: section.board, section: section %>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <% if policy(section).destroy? %>
        <%= link_to("Delete", board_section_path(section.board, sections.id), method: :delete) %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The board variable should be `nil` if you are using shallow routes, and `@board` if you are not, in the per-section edit form partial.

You will need to handle the different response formats in your controller:

```
class SectionsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @board = Board.find(params[:board_id]
        @section = board.sections.build(section_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @section.save
                format.html { redirect_to @board }
                format.js # renders app/views/sections/create.js.erb
            else
                format.html {}
                format.js
            end
        end
    end

    def update
        @section = Sections.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
            if @section.update(section_params)
                format.html { redirect_to section.board }
                format.js # renders app/views/sections/update.js.erb
            else
                format.html {}
                format.js
            end
        end
    end


    def section_params
        ...
    end
end
```

And your views:

```js
// create.js.erb
<% if @section.errors %>
    alert('could not save section');
<% else %>
    // clear new form, append new section
    document.getElementById('new_section').querySelector('input[name="section[name]"').value = "";
    document.getElementById('sections').innerHTML += "<%= j(render 'section', section: @section, index: @section.board.sections.count -1) %>"
<% end %>

// update.js.erb
<% if @section.errors %>
    alert('could not save section');
<% else %>
    alert('saved section');
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you for the helpful comment. I actually want to only display an edit form for a section when you click on "Edit" for that specific section. Currently all edit forms are shown and changes I make in any one of the forms are only applied after I reload the page

Comment: I added an example css style to hide to non-editing forms (is the `.hidden` class) and a simple example of the controller/views you would need to handle the section forms having Ajax support added when using `remote: true` on the form. I also extracted out a view partial for the section so you can use it on the normal page and reuse it in the `create.js.erb` template.